# in Ansible is it possible for a vars_prompt to allow tab autocomplete for a path?

Tags: variables, autocomplete, tabs, ansible, prompt

In an ansible playbook, I'm prompting the user for a path to a file.  I'd like to know if its possible to somehow integrate tab autocompletion for a path if they start typing to do this.  This is my current snippet for the prompt below-

```
vars_prompt:
- name: "deadline_linux_installers_tar"
  prompt: "What is the path to the deadline linux installers .tar?"
  default: "/vagrant/downloads/Deadline-10.0.23.4-linux-installers.tar"
  private: no
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

No

---

Or, the slightly smelly duct-tape-y way would be to wrap `ansible-playbook` in a script that **does** accept tab-completion, and then call `ansible-playbook -e "deadline_linux_installers_tar=$the_value" "$@"`